# Where can I find an implementation of the Cartesian Product Algorithm for Type Inference?

Tags: algorithm, types, type-inference, cartesian-product, selflanguage

Where can I find an implementation of [the cartesian product algorithm](http://selflanguage.org/_static/published/cpa.pdf) **for type inference?** (Preferably in Python/C++, but any language would really do.)

I've searched the internet many times but there are few details about the algorithm, and as far as I know, no published implementations.

Comment: this question is ***not*** about calculating c.p. of lists. it is about a type inference algorithm *using* c.p. of types, AFAICT from the linked paper (in the OO context, in the language Self). voted to reopen.

Comment: @WillNess -- Yes, you are correct. I forgot to mention that is the question. It's fixed now.

Comment: unfortunately, it's still not open. one more reopen vote is needed. I don't exactly know how to speed it up. there's some chat, or meta, or flagging for moderator assistance, but the last two are fraught with danger. moderator could rebuke your "incorrect flagging", and meta has its ["effect"](https://www.google.com/search?q=meta+effect). you never know. ([I never know](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=user%3a849891%20score%3a..-1%20is%3aq).)

Comment: @WillNess -- It's open now.

Comment: maybe try asking on cs.SE or cstheory.SE (according to their rules of course).